# How to inject service to class and then extend component with it?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-services

I have class `Layer`:

```
import {AfterViewInit, ViewChild} from 'angular2/core';


export class Layer implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('element') element;

  public canvas: HTMLCanvasElement = null;
  public context: CanvasRenderingContext2D = null;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.canvas = this.element.nativeElement;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
  }
}
```

which I will be extending with my component `Lines`:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

import {Layer} from './layer';
import {Game} from '../../providers/Game';


@Component({
  selector: 'lines-component',
  template: require('./template.html'),
  styles: [`
    canvas {
      z-index: 2;
    }
  `]
})
export class Lines extends Layer {
  constructor(public game: Game) {
    super();
  }
}
```

As you can see, I have to inject `Game` service to every component which will inherit from `Layer`. However, I would like to inject service to `Layer` class, so I can use it to create methods which depends on the service, and also it won't force me to inject service to the component on my own every single time.

Needless to say, injecting service to `Layer` as I would to any component is not working.

I am using angular 2.0.0-beta.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the constructor to the base class `Layer` just like you did on the extending class, and send the dependency as a parameter in the `super` method:

```
export class Layer implements AfterViewInit {
    constructor(public game: Game) {
        console.log(game);
    }
}

export class Lines extends Layer {
  constructor(public game: Game) {
    super(game);
  }
}
```

Comment: Kind of sad that I have to pass dependency as parameter to `super()`, but at least it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's something not supported by Angular. You need to have a constructor at the level of the component to define what you want to inject...

Using your sample:

```
export class Layer {
  constructor(public game: Game) {
  }
}

@Component({
  (...)
})
export class Lines extends Layer {
  (...)
}
```

If you have a look at the transpiled file for the `Lines` class, you see that the `game` parameter is present in the Lines constructor function and the `Game` service isn't present in the second parameter (the list of providers for the component) of the `__metadata` function:

```
Lines = (function (_super) {
  __extends(Lines, _super);
  function Lines() { // <------------------
    _super.apply(this, arguments);
  }
  Lines = __decorate([
    core_1.Component({
      selector: 'lines-component',
      template: "\n    lines\n  ",
      styles: ["\n    canvas {\n      z-index: 2;\n    }\n  "]
    }), 
    __metadata('design:paramtypes', []) // <------------------
  ], Lines);
  return Lines;
})(app_layer_component_1.Layer);
```

whereas you have it when defining `constructor(public game: Game)` in the `Lines` class:

```
Lines = (function (_super) {
  __extends(Lines, _super);
  function Lines(game) { // <------------------
    this.game = game;
  }
  Lines = __decorate([
    core_1.Component({
      selector: 'lines-component',
      template: "\n    lines\n  ",
      styles: ["\n    canvas {\n      z-index: 2;\n    }\n  "]
    }), 
    __metadata('design:paramtypes', [app_game_service_1.Game]) // <------------------
  ], Lines);
  return Lines;
})(app_layer_component_1.Layer);
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: It is interesting, maybe injection is possible only when class have some decorator specified?