# How to inject existing model hierarchy classes, with Angular 2 services through DI

Tags: angular

With a model hierarchy like this:

```
export class A {
   constructor() {
      // Here service X is needed for some own functions
   }
}

export class B extends A {
   constructor() {
      // Here service Y is needed for some own functions
      super( ... )
   }
}

export class C extends B {
   constructor(parent, data) {
        super( ... )
   }
}
```

I want to instance C objects. So the questions are:

**How do i inject `X` and `Y` services?**

- Should i put all of them on the `C` constructor, and pass them to the base classes with `super`?
- Can they be mixed with the already existing parameters `parent` and `data` ?
- There is some way i can inject only `Y` at the `B` level, and `X` at the `A` level? So somehow i avoid passing those references on the `super`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export class A {
  constructor(serviceX: ServiceX) {
    // Here service X is needed for some own functions
    this.serviceX = serviceX;
  }
}

export class B extends A {
  constructor(serviceX: ServiceX, private _serviceY: ServiceY) {
    // Here service Y is needed for some own functions
    super(serviceX);
    this.servicxY = serviceY;
  }
}

export class C extends B {
  constructor(serviceX: ServiceX, serviceY: ServiceY) {
    super(_serviceX, serviceY);
  }
}
```

See also [Angular2 access global service without including it in every constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35206821/angular2-access-global-service-without-including-it-in-every-constructor/35207105#35207105)