# Angular2 no provider for service error

Tags: typescript, angular

From [Angular2 access global service without including it in every constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35206821/angular2-access-global-service-without-including-it-in-every-constructor) I have grabbed the code and slightly modified it into:

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
  constructor(public http: Http) {}

  get(url: string) {
    return http.get(url);
  }

}

@Injectable()
export abstract class BaseService {
  constructor(protected serv: ApiService) {}  
}

@Injectable()
export class MediaService extends BaseService {

  // Why do we need this?
  constructor(s: ApiService) {
    super(s)
  }

  makeCall() {
    this.serv.get("http://www.example.com/get_data")
  }

}
```

However, when I try to run this code I get an error in the console:

> NoProviderError {message: "No provider for ApiService! (App ->
>   MediaService -> ApiService)", stack: "Error: DI Exception↵

I have created a Plunkr with the code at https://plnkr.co/edit/We2k9PDsYMVQWguMhhGl

Does anyone know what causes this  error?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to also define `ApiService` in the `providers` attribute.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [MediaService, ApiService], // <-----
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class App {
  constructor(mediaService: MediaService) {
    this.name = 'Angular2'

    console.log('start');

    mediaService.makeCall();
  }
}
```

It's because injectors are relied on components. If you want to have more details about how to inject a service into a service, you could have a look at this question:

- [What's the best way to inject one service into another in angular 2 (Beta)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804298/whats-the-best-way-to-inject-one-service-into-another-in-angular-2-beta/34807397)